# Code efficiency in Node.js for multiple events listeners

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom-events, hapi.js, eventemitter

I have a code that emits and handles events in same .js file. Emitting events can be of type "hello", "world", "user", etc as an example. All the event handler functions (.on) have similar approach to handle events inside core functions of error and callbacks (exactly same). Is there a suggestion to refactor and improve the redundant code.

```
localEvents.on("hello", function(request , reply){
    console.log("inside event for hello");
    hello.intialize() {
       // handle initialise error and callback //
    };
});

localEvents.on("world", function(request , reply){
    console.log("inside event for world");
    world.initialise() {
       // handle initialise error and callback //
    };
});

localEvents.on("user", function(request , reply){
    console.log("inside event for user");
    user.initialise() {
       // handle initialise error and callback //
    };
});

localEvents.emit(task, request, reply);
```

Comment: Can you tell me what is "request" and "reply" in the function parameters?

Comment: request and reply are hapi server objects, like req and rep in express.

Answer (score 5):

You could create a helper function, like:

```
function addHandler(evName, obj) {
  localEvents.on(evName, function(request, reply) {
    console.log("inside event for %s", evName);
    obj.initialise(function(err) {
       // handle initialise error and callback
    });
  });
}
```

Then just call it like:

```
addHandler('hello', hello);
addHandler('world', world);
addHandler('user', user);
```

Or if you really want to cut down on even the repetition in the arguments you might create a helper like:

```
function addHandler(evName) {
  var obj = eval(evName);
  localEvents.on(evName, function(request, reply) {
    console.log("inside event for %s", evName);
    obj.initialise(function(err) {
       // handle initialise error and callback
    });
  });
}
```

Allowing you to then to simply do:

```
addHandler('hello');
addHandler('world');
addHandler('user');
```

Comment: How are we going to emit the event `localEvents.emit(task, request, reply);` in above approach?

Comment: @user3601166 - the `.emit()` is exactly the same as it was before.  your `localEvents` variable is unchanged so you just so `localEvents.emit(...)` like you were doing before.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Understand.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way of doing this - 
This way will be more flexible to any changes that you might need to make in the events callback functions

```
var eventsList = {
    "hello": function(request, reply) {
        console.log("inside event for hello");
        hello.initialise() {
            // handle initialise error and callback //
        };
    },
    "world": function(request, reply) {
        console.log("inside event for world");
        world.initialise() {
            // handle initialise error and callback //
        };
    },
    "user": function(request, reply) {
        console.log("inside event for user");
        user.initialise() {
            // handle initialise error and callback //
        };
    }
}

function generateEvents(events){
    for(var e in events){
        localEvents.on(e, events.e)
    }
}

generateEvents(eventsList)
```

Comment: How are we to emit events here?

Comment: While this is a different way to organize the code, it doesn't really eliminate much of the copied/duplicated code so I'm not sure how this really increases the code efficiency that I think the OP was asking for.

Comment: The event emit still remains the same way you did

Comment: @jfriend00 yes you are right but in the real world the code will not be as simple as depicted here .. you will always have to compromise on atleast something flexibility vs dupicacy of code as the they both are inversely proportional